# Не получается обработать собственный класс исключения

Tags: c#, исключения

1. Пытаюсь подключится к серверу через **HttpClient**

   ```
       try
       {
           HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
           var result = await httpclient.GetStringAsync("Адрес");
           dynamic x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
           Temperature = x.main.temp;

       }
   ```
2. В строке "Адрес" пишу неправильный путь, чтобы вызвать и словить исключение...

   ```
      catch (Exception httpex)
       {

          throw new HttpException("Не удалось выполнить подключение к узлу", httpex.InnerException, httpex.Source);
       }
   ```
3. Передаю информацию в собственный класс **HttpException**, где вызываю метод(и передаю ему параметры), который производит запись в xml файл.

   ```
   [Serializable]
   public class HttpException : Exception
   {
   public HttpException() { }
   public HttpException(string message) : base(message) { }
   public HttpException(string message, Exception inner, string source)
               :base(message, inner)
           {
               XmlLog.Write(message, inner, source);
           }
   protected HttpException(
       System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
       System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
   ```

Так вот. По окончании записи в xml файл, оператор вновь возвращается к строке где начиналась инициализация исключения

```
throw new HttpException("Не удалось выполнить подключение к узлу", httpex.InnerException, httpex.Source);
```

И потом выдает мне исключение, где говорит, что мое собственное исключение"HttpException" не было обработано пользователем.
Я никак не могу понять где я совершаю ошибку. Судя по отладке, всё что происходит в моем классе(HttpException), в том числе работа с xml, происходит без ошибок.

Comment: А вы поставьте breakpoint на catch и посмотрите. И ещё, добавьте в хвост `catch /*без параметров*/ { /* и breakpoint вот здесь */ }`

Comment: Происходит ровно то, что вы попросили. `throw new HttpException(...)`= `выбросить новое исключение_имеющее_класс_HttpException`

Comment: VladD: не совсем уловил мысль. Если можно, поясните цель.
4per: Хорошо, а как же тогда "правильно" обрабатывать исключения с собственной генерацией классов?

Comment: Вот вы пишите `... чтобы вызвать и словить исключение ...`. Далее отрывок текста программы, в котором `вызвать` действительно есть, но где же `словить`? Если у вас нет `словить`, значит его словит runtime и правильно сообщит, что ему пришлось словить его вместо пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Для обработки исключения используется конструкция [**try-catch**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx), которую вы использовали.

Слово [**throw**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx) используется для генерации исключения.

**Вот что происходит у вас в коде:**

После того как в блоке `try` возникает исключительная ситуация, управление переходит блоку `catch`, где вы генерируете вручную новое не обработанное исключение.

*(Потому-что внутри блока `catch` нет очередной конструкции `try`. Оно там в принципе и не нужно потому-что писать обработчик исключений в обработчике исключений это глупость)*

Если я правильно понимаю вашу цель, то вы хотите написать что-то вроде логгера который будет складывать_в_xml/выводить_на_экран/отправлять_по_сети сообщение об ошибке.

Вот вам пример элементарного логгера, модифицировать его дальше можно в меру своей распущенности. :)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public static  class Logger
    {
        public static void Log(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);

        }

        public static void Log(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("pew pew");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Log(e);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Так-же я думаю что можно найти много вариантов готовых логгеров в интернете, один из которых точно вам подойдёт.